# Complex criteria for counting occurrences

Tags: libreoffice-calc

For a survey (consisting of +2000 entries per table) I need to perform a difficult sum operation on the following two tables (simplified).

Table A:

```
  |   id    sex
--+---------------
1 |   101    m
2 |   102    w
3 |   103    w
4 |   104    m
```

Table B:

```
  |   id    a    b
--+------------------
1 |   101   1    1
2 |   102   1    0
3 |   103   0    0
4 |   104   1    1
```

The values for attribute 'a' and 'b' are meant to be yes (1) and no (0).
I now want to count the occurrence of value 1 in column 'a' for each male person ('m').

For this example the result would be `2`.

You can use [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjlm6bfo887ws6l/test.ods?dl=0) (test.odt) as a starting point, if you intend to help.

How would someone do that? Is this even possible in Libre Calc, or should I use SQL?

Comment: Very clear question -- good job.  The only thing that could improve it is describing the attempts you have made to solve it.  For example, have you looked at any Calc functions that didn't work, and if so, what were they.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done a test, but I think it is definitely possible in Calc.  You want a combination of [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) AND [SUMIFS](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/SUMIFS_function), and knowledge of [Array functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#What_is_an_array_formula.3F).

Basically you want to use `SUMIFS` on column B of Table B, referencing the gender using `VLOOKUP`.

So, using your example tables, in B6 of table B:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B5; B2:B5; VLOOKUP({A};TableA!$A$2:$B$5; 2)="m")
```

I'm not sure if the '{A}' is the correct syntax to make the Lookup work in array fashion.

Alternately, you could insert a column between 'id' and 'a' in Table B, use `VLOOKUP` to work out the gender, and then use `SUMIFS` on whether the (new) second column contains "m".

**EDIT:**  Cancel that

It appears Vlookup can't be used in array formulae, so that doesn't work.  However, try this in B6:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B5*(LOOKUP(A2:A5,Sheet1.A2:Sheet1.A5,Sheet1.B2:Sheet1.B5)="m"))
```

Table A is in Sheet1, Table B is in Sheet2.

Comment: When entering into a new cell within Table B the second search criterion I use is ``(B2:B5; B2:B5; "=1")``, but the VLOOKUP criterion throws an Err:512. The first criterion should be the list of men IDs.

Comment: For me your second suggestion - about adding the gender in a separate column for each corresponding ID - isn't optimal, because I don't want redundant data.

Comment: [SUMPRODUCT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#SUMPRODUCT) to the rescue!  It's amazing how many different kinds of problems that function can solve.